# "Error: Can't convert <haven_labelled> to character"

Tags: character, frequency, numeric, r-haven, labelled-generic

My student and I both loaded the same dataset, installed the same packages, and were running the same code. When I run "frq" I get a frequency table and the variable is labeled as "numeric." When my student runs the same code, she gets `"Error: Can't convert <haven_labelled> to character."`

Any thoughts on where we might be going wrong?

Answer (score 7):

I got same problem.
I used library(tidyverse) and it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Load the library haven and it should work. It's working fine for me in 2023.

```
install.packages(haven)
library(haven)
```

Answer (score 2):

I could say it with more certainty if you had provided an [Minimal, Reproducible Example (MWE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

However, borrowing from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65595475/2275986), the error that you get is most probably because the variable in question is of the type `haven_labelled`, which not all `R` functions can deal with.

You should, in principle, be able to solve the issue by changing the variable type to `R`-friendly `factor` using `haven::as_factor`.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, similar in the sense that when I tried to coerce a varriable to 'character', I got a similar error report. I used library(haven) and it worked for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).