# Ggplot error : haven_labelled/vctrs_vctr/double

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

I am new here and still studying R so I am dealing with an error.

Here is what I get from console

> Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type haven_labelled/vctrs_vctr/double. Defaulting to continuous.

I don't know what can I do to make it work. I want to get a scatterplot.

```
ggplot(data = diagnoza, aes(x = Plecc, y = P32.01))
```

Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type haven_labelled/vctrs_vctr/double. Defaulting to continuous.

Comment: Please post your code as text, not a screenshot.

Comment: We need to call geom_point, something like `ggplot(...) + geom_point()`

Comment: Still, doesn't work ;/

Comment: Hi Marcin. Welcome to SO! To help us to help you could you please make your issue reproducible by sharing a sample of your **data**? See [how to make a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Simply type `dput(diagnoza)` into the console and copy & paste the output starting with `structure(....` into your post. If your dataset has a lot of observations you could do `dput(head(diagnoza, 20))` for the first twenty rows of data or `dput(head(diagnoza[, c("Plecc", "P32.01")], 20))` for only the cols used in the plot.

Comment: Alright so I typed the last command cause I have 2000 observations and those are my results.

Comment: > dput(head(diagnoza[, c("Plecc", "P32.01")], 20))
structure(list(Plecc = c(2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2), P32.01 = structure(c(3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 4, 3, 5, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 3, 4, 5), label = "P32.01. odpoczynek w domu (oglądanie TV)", format.spss = "F1.0", display_width = 12L, labels = c(Nigdy = 1, 
Rzadko = 2, `Od czasu do czasu` = 3, Często = 4, `Bardzo często` = 5
), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double"))), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding `geom_point` as suggested by @zx8754 gives me a scatter plot. There is still the warning you reported which is related to some of your variables being of type `haven_labelled`, so I guess you imported your data from SPSS.

To get rid of this warning you could convert your variables to R factors using `haven::as_factor`. Probably it would be best to do that for the whole dataset after importing your data.

```r
diagnoza <- structure(list(Plecc = c(2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 
                                     1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2), P32.01 = structure(c(3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 
                                                                                   5, 5, 4, 3, 5, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 3, 4, 5), label = "P32.01. odpoczynek w domu (oglądanie TV)", format.spss = "F1.0", display_width = 12L, labels = c(Nigdy = 1, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           Rzadko = 2, `Od czasu do czasu` = 3, Często = 4, `Bardzo często` = 5
                                                                                   ), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double"))), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                           -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

library(haven)
library(ggplot2)

# Convert labelled vector to a factor
diagnoza$P32.01 <- haven::as_factor(diagnoza$P32.01)

ggplot(data = diagnoza, aes(x = Plecc, y = P32.01)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: Hooray for 'this question has been asked before'. Why it's not coming up in the search results for the error message I do not know.